# PHP Insert a multidimensional array into a regular array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a regular array called *$input* Input looks like the following:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
```

I want to insert

```
$a = array("black","maroon");
```

into the array so that I would get:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => Array([0] => black [1] => maroon ) [4] => yellow)
```

using:

```
array_splice($input, -1, 1, array("black", "maroon"));
```

However, when I run this I get:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => black [4] => maroon )
```

How can I adjust this to get the desired outcome?

Comment: so basically substitute `"yellow"` element with `$a` ? or is there anything more??

Comment: There is a mistake, yellow shouldn't be replaced. I updated the question.

Comment: so insert the new array before the last element??

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I'm looking for. $input[3] = $a is close, but that overwrites the element.

Comment: check if my answer if it suitable for u...

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do this:

```
$input[3] = $a;
```

Comment: what if there are more elements in array??

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `array_push()`

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_pop($input);
$a = array("black","maroon");

array_push($input,$a);

print_r($input);
```

See [demo here](https://eval.in/475913)(with index yellow)

With `array_pop()`, see demo [here](https://eval.in/475915) (replacing last index, ie yellow)

Comment: This would leave the 'yellow' array item which is not present in the desired output array

Comment: my bad. I'll be in my corner sobbing

Comment: What if I want it in a different position, e.g 2?

Comment: @user2694306 use `unset($index);`, it will remove specified index.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input[count($input)+1] = $a;
```

Do that as many time as you need, with as many arrays you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an indexed array, this will first push all element forward by 1 offset with faking a new replacement. Then you can insert with that key

```
$arr1 = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr2 = array("a", "b");
$offset = 2;
array_splice($arr1, $offset, 0, "");
$arr1[$offset] = $arr2;
```

`arr1` output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Comment: This is almost there. What is it wasn't the last element, but the array was being inserted to the second one?

Comment: what do you mean by second one??

Comment: I mean $arr[2] or any other index for that matter